# STM32L432 full duplex DMA SPI slave locks up after communication starts

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, spi, c++, dma

I am continuously sending a substantial amount of data between the STM32L432 and a FPGA using SPI in full-duplex mode. I decided to implement DMA on the L432 in order to increase the transfer rate between the two devices.

When I start the communication between the two, the L432 locks up and remains unresponsive. I have a LED in the interrupt service routines for testing purposes which is to be toggled when the ISR is being serviced but the program does not reach that point. I have been trying to solve this problem for days now and have no idea what is causing this to happen.

This is how I set up the SPI and the DMA:

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "DMA_SPI.h"

int16_t data_to_transmit[10];
int16_t received_data[10];
DigitalOut myled(LED1);

void SPI_DMA_init() {
    myled = 1;                                                                  //toggle LED on

    //Deinitialise
    SPI_DMA_SLAVE_deinit();
    deinitDMA();

    //Initialise
    initDMA();
    SPI_DMA_SLAVE_init(); 

    //Start DMA communication
    startCommunication();     
}    

/* Starting DMA communication according to STM32L432 Reference Manual p1317-p1318*/
void startCommunication() {

    SET_SPI1_CR2_RXDMAEN_BIT();                                                 //Enable RX DMA buffer
    DMA1_CH3_ENABLE();                                                          //Enable DMA channel 3      
    DMA1_CH2_ENABLE();                                                          //Enable DMA channel 2
    SET_SPI1_CR2_TXDMAEN_BIT();                                                 //Enable TX DMA buffer              
    SPI1_ENABLE();                                                              //SPI module enabled

}


//====================================================DEINITIALISE=========================================================================
void SPI_DMA_SLAVE_deinit() {
    //Disable the clocks
    RCC->AHB2ENR &= ~(RCC_AHB2ENR_GPIOAEN);                                      
    RCC->APB2ENR &=  ~(RCC_APB2ENR_SPI1EN);      

    //Clear pin settings
    GPIOA->MODER&=~((3u<<(2*CS_slave)));                                         //clear GPIOA pin mode (in input mode when reset)

    GPIOA->MODER&=~(                                                             //clear GPIOB
            (3u<<(2*SCK_slave))
            |(3u<<(2*MISO_slave))
            |(3u<<(2*MOSI_slave))
            |0x03
                );

    GPIOA->AFR[0]&=~(                                                            //clear alternate function selector bits
            (0x0f<<(4*SCK_slave))
            |(0x0f<<(4*MISO_slave))
            |(15u<<(4*MOSI_slave))
            );

    //Clear SPI bits
    SPI1_DISABLE();
    CLEAR_SPI1_CR1_MSTR_BIT();
    CLEAR_SPI1_CR1_BR_BITS();
    CLEAR_SPI1_CR1_SSM_BIT();
    CLEAR_SPI1_CR1_SSI_BIT();
    CLEAR_SPI1_CR1_CPOL_BIT();
    CLEAR_SPI1_CR1_CPHA_BIT();


    CLEAR_SPI1_CR2_DS_BITS();
    CLEAR_SPI1_CR2_RXDMAEN_BIT();
    CLEAR_SPI1_CR2_TXDMAEN_BIT();
    CLEAR_SPI1_CR2_RXEIE_BIT();
    CLEAR_SPI1_CR2_TXEIE_BIT();


}

void deinitDMA() {
    RCC->AHB1ENR &= ~(RCC_AHB1ENR_DMA1EN);                                      //Disable the DMA1 clock

    //Disable channels
    DMA1_CH2_DISABLE();
    DMA1_CH3_DISABLE();

    CLEAR_DMA1_SPI1RX_CSELR_BITS();                                             //deselect SPI1_Rx on DMA1 Channel 2
    CLEAR_DMA1_SPI1TX_CSELR_BITS();                                             //deselect SPI1_Tx on DMA1 Channel 3


//-----------------------------------------------Receive-----------------------------------------------------                       
   //Clear configuration bits                     
   CLEAR_DMA1_CH2_CCR_DIR_BIT();                                                
   CLEAR_DMA1_CH2_CCR_PSIZE_BITS();
   CLEAR_DMA1_CH2_CCR_MSIZE_BITS();
   CLEAR_DMA1_CH2_CCR_MINC_BIT();
   CLEAR_DMA1_CH2_CCR_PINC_BIT();
   CLEAR_DMA1_CH2_CCR_TCIE_BIT();
   CLEAR_DMA1_CH2_CCR_CIRC_BIT();
   CLEAR_DMA1_CH2_CCR_MEM2MEM_BIT();
   CLEAR_DMA1_CH2_CCR_PL_BITS();
   CLEAR_DMA1_CH2_CCR_TEIE_BIT();

   CLEAR_DMA1_CH2_CNDTR_BITS();
   CLEAR_DMA1_CH2_CPAR_BITS();
   CLEAR_DMA1_CH2_CMAR_BITS();
//-----------------------------------------------Receive-----------------------------------------------------   

//-----------------------------------------------Transmission------------------------------------------------  
    //Clear configuration bits 
    CLEAR_DMA1_CH3_CCR_DIR_BIT();
    CLEAR_DMA1_CH3_CCR_PSIZE_BITS();
    CLEAR_DMA1_CH3_CCR_MSIZE_BITS();
    CLEAR_DMA1_CH3_CCR_MINC_BIT();
    CLEAR_DMA1_CH3_CCR_PINC_BIT();
    CLEAR_DMA1_CH3_CCR_TCIE_BIT();
    CLEAR_DMA1_CH3_CCR_CIRC_BIT();
    CLEAR_DMA1_CH3_CCR_MEM2MEM_BIT();
    CLEAR_DMA1_CH3_CCR_PL_BITS();
    CLEAR_DMA1_CH3_CCR_TEIE_BIT();

    CLEAR_DMA1_CH3_CNDTR_BITS();
    CLEAR_DMA1_CH3_CPAR_BITS();
    CLEAR_DMA1_CH3_CMAR_BITS();

//-----------------------------------------------Transmission------------------------------------------------    

    NVIC->ISER[0]&= ~(1u<<12);                                                   //Disable DMA1 channel 2 interrupt                                                   
    NVIC->ISER[0]&= ~(1u<<13);                                                   //Disable DMA1 channel 3 interrupt

}
//====================================================DEINITIALISE=========================================================================



void SPI_DMA_SLAVE_init() {
    RCC->AHB2ENR|= (RCC_AHB2ENR_GPIOAEN);                                       //GPIO A clock enable       
    RCC->APB2ENR|=RCC_APB2ENR_SPI1EN;                                           //Enable SPI1 Clock

   //SET SCK, MISO, MOSI and CS pins 
    GPIOA->MODER|=(                                                             
            (2u<<(2*SCK_slave))
            |(2u<<(2*MISO_slave))
            |(2u<<(2*MOSI_slave))
            |0x01
                );

    //SET pins to function as SPI pins
    GPIOA->AFR[0]|=(                                                             
            (5u<<(4*SCK_slave))
            |(5u<<(4*MISO_slave))
            |(5u<<(4*MOSI_slave))
                );

    SET_SPI1_CR1_BR_BITS();                                                     //baud rate bits set 1/16 giving 1MHz SCK frequency
    SET_SPI1_CR1_CPOL_BIT();                                                    //CPOL = 1
    SET_SPI1_CR1_CPHA_BIT();                                                    //CPHA = 1                                                  


    SET_SPI1_CR2_DS_BITS();                                                     //Data Size = 16 bits
    SET_SPI1_CR2_RXDMAEN_BIT();                                                 //Rx buffer DMA enable
    SET_SPI1_CR2_TXDMAEN_BIT();                                                 //Tx buffer DMA enable


}



void initDMA() {
    RCC->AHB1ENR|= (RCC_AHB1ENR_DMA1EN);                                        //Enable the DMA1 clock

    DMA1_CH2_DISABLE();                                                         //Disable DMA channel 2
    DMA1_CH3_DISABLE();                                                         //Disable DMA channel 3

    SET_DMA1_SPI1RX_CSELR_BITS();                                               //Select SPI1_Rx on DMA1 Channel 2
    SET_DMA1_SPI1TX_CSELR_BITS();                                               //Select SPI1_Tx on DMA1 Channel 3

//-----------------------------------------------Receive-----------------------------------------------------                         
   CLEAR_DMA1_CH2_CCR_DIR_BIT();                                                //Peripheral->Memory
   SET_DMA1_CH2_CCR_PSIZE_BITS();                                               //16 bits
   SET_DMA1_CH2_CCR_MSIZE_BITS();                                               //16 bits
   SET_DMA1_CH2_CCR_MINC_BIT();                                                 //Memory increment mode
   SET_DMA1_CH2_CCR_PINC_BIT();                                                 //Peripheral increment mode
   SET_DMA1_CH2_CCR_TCIE_BIT();                                                 //Transfer complete interrupt enable
   SET_DMA1_CH2_CCR_CIRC_BIT();                                                 //Circular Buffer mode
   SET_DMA1_CH2_CCR_PL_BITS();                                                  //Priority Level = Highest

    DMA1_Channel2->CNDTR = 10;                                                  //number of data to transfer from the peripheral to memory.
    DMA1_Channel2->CPAR = (int32_t)&SPI1->DR;                                   //Source Adddress = SPI data register
    DMA1_Channel2->CMAR = (int32_t)received_data;                               //Destination address = received_data array
//-----------------------------------------------Receive-----------------------------------------------------   

//-----------------------------------------------Transmission------------------------------------------------  

   SET_DMA1_CH3_CCR_DIR_BIT();                                                  //Memory->Peripheral
   SET_DMA1_CH3_CCR_PSIZE_BITS();                                               //16 bits
   SET_DMA1_CH3_CCR_MSIZE_BITS();                                               //16 bits
   SET_DMA1_CH3_CCR_MINC_BIT();                                                 //Memory increment mode
   SET_DMA1_CH3_CCR_PINC_BIT();                                                 //Peripheral increment mode
   SET_DMA1_CH3_CCR_TCIE_BIT();                                                 //Transfer complete interrupt enable
   SET_DMA1_CH3_CCR_CIRC_BIT();                                                 //Circular Buffer mode
   SET_DMA1_CH3_CCR_PL_BITS();                                                  //Priority Level = Highest

    DMA1_Channel3->CNDTR = 10;                                                  //number of data to transfer from memory to the peripheral
    DMA1_Channel3->CPAR = (int32_t)&SPI1->DR;                                   //Destination address = SPI data register
    DMA1_Channel3->CMAR = (int32_t)data_to_transmit;                            //Source address = data_to_transmit
//-----------------------------------------------Transmission------------------------------------------------    


    NVIC->ISER[0]|= (1u<<12);                                                   //Enable DMA1 channel 2 interrupt                                                   
    NVIC->ISER[0]|= (1u<<13);                                                   //Enable DMA1 channel 3 interrupt
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel2_IRQn);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel3_IRQn);

}


//Interrupt Handler for DMA1 Channel 2
void DMA1_Channel2_IRQHandler(void) {
     myled = 0;                                                                 //Toggle LED off
     CLEAR_DMA1_CH2_IFCR_GFLAG();                                               //Clear Global Interrupt flag
}


//Interrupt Handler for DMA1 Channel 3
void DMA1_Channel3_IRQHandler(void) {
     myled = 0;  
     CLEAR_DMA1_CH3_IFCR_GFLAG();                                               //Clear Global Interrupt flag             
}
```

Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: Would suggest you move from LEDs to toggling GPIOs and get that and the SPI itself on a cheap USB based logic analyzer.  Then run it all with the debugger connected and a breakpoint in the hardfault hander, and if still inconclusive stop it with the debugger and see where it is...

Comment: Also, really look at the behind the scenes code... there is a some *eye opening* stuff deep in the internals of mbed that may prove quite a bit different than what you might imagine from the outside.

Comment: Not sure if only problem, but at your deinit functions you disable clock first and then you try clear settings.

Comment: @Rokta You are correct, I have changed my code to disable the clock after I clear the bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem. Because I am using a C++, I needed to use extern "C" on the interrupt handlers according to [this](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkgLCSAZ/how-to-setup-interrupts-correctly) post. My interrupt handlers are now written like this:

```
extern "C" void DMA1_Channel2_IRQHandler(void) {
         myled = 0;                                                                 //Toggle LED off
         CLEAR_DMA1_CH2_IFCR_GFLAG();                                               //Clear Global Interrupt flag
}
```